# Javascript - Remove Parent Table within child tables when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, removechild

I've wrote some code to remove the parent tables within a container where a checkbox is checked. It works on the first element properly.

But when I try to remove multiple elements by checked all three checkboxes, it throws error - `elements[i] becomes undefined`.

I've seen other solutions for doing this but they don't seem to apply exactly to what I'm doing with removing all selected tables within a container.

Please let me know, what I'm doing wrong.

```js
function deleteTables(tableClass,containerID){
 var container = document.getElementById(containerID);
 var elements = container.getElementsByClassName(tableClass);
 var tableCount = elements.length;
 for(var i=0; i<tableCount; i++) {
  var inputList = elements[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
  var inputListCount = inputList.length;
  for(var x=0; x<inputListCount; x++) {
   if (inputList[x].type == "checkbox" && inputList[x].checked == true)
   {
    container.removeChild(elements[i]);
    break;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Table" onclick="deleteTables('dataTable','test_div')" />

<DIV id="test_div">
  <TABLE class="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
    <TR>
      <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></TD>
      <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txtA[]"/></TD>
      <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txtB[]"/></TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  
  <TABLE class="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
    <TR>
      <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></TD>
      <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txtA[]"/></TD>
      <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txtB[]"/></TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  
  <TABLE class="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
    <TR>
      <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></TD>
      <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txtA[]"/></TD>
      <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txtB[]"/></TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
</DIV>
```

Comment: in which browser are you checking - seems working fine in chrome browser.

Comment: Just a quick pointer, don't use capitals for your tags and if you want to use a width attribute you need to drop the px e.g. width="350" - however you should really be using CSS for this anyway.

Comment: I'm using firefox. If you select multiple boxes it doesn't remove them all. even when running the code snippet here.

Comment: After deleting the record,  decrement the record count . Because after deleting record array will get rearranged automatically.  If you are decrementing count after removal at some point of time it vl point to unavailable record.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a `--i` before the `break`.

You've removed the element at `i`, so the next one, which would have been at `i+1`, will now be at `i`.  Since the `for (var i=0;...)` loop will increment `i`, you have to decrement it to counter that.

Also, you should probably get rid of `tableCount=elements.length` and use `elements.length` directly in the loop, since you're modifying `elements` as you go.

Comment: You're right, this solves the issue of it not deleting all the selected ones. However, I'm still getting the "TypeError: elements[i] is undefined" error in the firefox debugger.

Comment: That's because of my second point (which I just added in an edit) about using storing elements.length rather than using it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to minus one value (-1) from the **tableCount** value and also in **i** value

```js
   function deleteTables(tableClass,containerID){
 var container = document.getElementById(containerID);
 var elements = container.getElementsByClassName(tableClass);
 var tableCount = elements.length;
 for(var i=0; i<tableCount; i++) {
  var inputList = elements[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
  var inputListCount = inputList.length;                      
  for(var x=0; x<inputListCount; x++) {
   if (inputList[x].type == "checkbox" && inputList[x].checked == true)
   {
       container.removeChild(elements[i]);
                            tableCount--;
                            i--;
              break;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Table" onclick="deleteTables('dataTable','test_div')" />

<DIV id="test_div">
  <TABLE class="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
    <TR>
      <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></TD>
      <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txtA[]"/></TD>
      <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txtB[]"/></TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  
  <TABLE class="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
    <TR>
      <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></TD>
      <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txtA[]"/></TD>
      <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txtB[]"/></TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
  
  <TABLE class="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
    <TR>
      <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></TD>
      <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txtA[]"/></TD>
      <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txtB[]"/></TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
</DIV>
```

Hope this will help you.